# i keep getting 'my_time' is not defined.I don't understand why

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import webbrowser
from datetime import datetime
import time

def open_inTime():

    now = datetime.now()
    my_time = now.time()

if my_time >= time(14,50) and my_time <= time(16,00):

    webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com")
else:
    print("Time to open webbrowser is long over due")

open_inTime()
```

Comment: I am using Python, I am using Python 3.6.4

Comment: Ok. Do you know how indentation works in Python?

Comment: I am not sure , so what i do I usually put everything in one line and tab and it puts in the correct indentation,if not i get an error when i run. Now I spaced everything apart because  I wanted the code to be clear.

Comment: Please go through a Python tutorial. The fault in your code is so obviously caused by lack of basics. Asking questions about programming here is good and fine, but it's not a replacement for going through a tutorial first.

Comment: i did and i was testing my self with this code. I am currently on If statements. declaring variables and place holders is what has been confusing me. I even declared on the Main  Function and it still gave me an error.That is why i chose to finally seek help here

Comment: Specifically, you need to go through a tutorial that teaches how functions work. The problem here is that the if statement is outside the function but the variables are defined inside the function, so you end up running the if statement before you call the function and define the variables.

Comment: okay Thank you,I will look at it

Comment: Please post your question in the body of the post and not just in the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I think you are trying to achieve:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

def open_inTime():
    return datetime.now().time()

start_time = datetime.strptime('14:50', '%H:%M').time()
end_time = datetime.strptime('16:00', '%H:%M').time()

if start_time <= open_inTime() <= end_time:
    print('Success!')
else:
    print("Time to open webbrowser is long over due")
```

**Explanation**

- In general, use functions to `return` values.
- Define time objects from strings and assign them to variables.
- Use chained comparisons as this is more efficient and readable.

Comment: I see it now, all i needed to was  to call the function. I will look at the tutorials for Functions. Thank you so much